# How to change vertically splitted screnn to horizontal layout in conemu

Tags: display, tmux, conemu, layout, rotate

Is there a possibility to change layout in CONEMU for already existing splits in scree. Lets say i would like to change this:

```
+---+---+     +-------+
|   |   |     |   1   |
| 1 | 2 | to  +-------+
|   |   |     |   2   |
+---+---+     +-------+
```

or this:

```
+---+---+     +---+---+
|   | 2 |     |   | 1 |
| 1 +---+  to | 3 +---+
|   | 3 |     |   | 2 |
+---+---+     +---+---+
```

If i remember properly TMUX has some feature called "rotate" or something...

Thanks in advance